# Magento how to check if Admin is logged in (Frontend)

Tags: php, magento

How can I check if the admin user is logged in on the frontend since the cookies for the frontend and the backend are splitted?

Comment: `Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Apparently if `session_save_path` is "set" on memcache (it stores the session into memcache the `session_save` node is ignored and the session will be saved into memcache
I have searched this question on the web(stackoverflow and magento stack have got some of these questions open), but with poor results except for a german guy who was talking about retrieving the session file, so I decided to extend this solution to all the possible values of `session_save` node inside `app/etc/local.xml`, I have placed this code inside `Helper/Data.php` class.
It's far  from being good, but as a starting point could be ok

```
//  Redis library: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession
public function isAdmin(){

        if(array_key_exists('adminhtml', $_COOKIE)){

            $locaXml = Mage::getBaseDir('etc').DS.'local.xml';
            $xml = new DOMDocument();
            $xml->load($locaXml);
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
            $entry = $xpath->query("//session_save");

            foreach($entry as $ent){
              $saveMethod = trim($ent->nodeValue);
            }

            $saveMethod = (!empty($saveMethod)) ? trim($saveMethod):'files';                

            if(Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Cm_RedisSession')->is('active', 'true') && $saveMethod=='db'){
                $entry = $xpath->query("//redis_session");
                if($entry->length>0)
                    $saveMethod='redis';
            }

        switch ($saveMethod) {
            case 'db':
                $read = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                $query = $read->select()->from(Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('core/session'))
                                        ->where('session_id=?',$_COOKIE['adminhtml'])
                                        ->limit(1);
                $sessionDb = $read->fetchAll($query);
                if(count($sessionDb)==0)
                    return false;

                $session_data = $sessionDb[0]['session_data'];
                break;

            case 'files':

                $session_path=Mage::getBaseDir('session').DS.'sess_'.$_COOKIE['adminhtml'];
                if(!is_file($session_path))
                    return false;

                $session_data = file_get_contents($session_path);
                break;

            case 'memcached':   
            case 'memcache':
                if(!isset($session_path)){
                    $entry = $xpath->query("//session_save_path");
                    foreach($entry as $ent){
                      $session_path = $ent->nodeValue;
                    }
                }
                $timeout=null;
                if(strpos($session_path,'?')){
                    $session_path=(explode('?',$session_path,2));
                    $host_port=$session_path[0];

                    preg_match('@\&?timeout=([0-9]+)\&?|$@',$session_path[1],$match);
                    $timeout= (isset($match[1]))? $match[1]:null;
                }

                $host_port=explode(':',$host_port);
                $index=count($host_port)-1;
                $port= $host_port[$index];
                unset($host_port[$index]);
                $host=implode(':',$host_port);

                if($saveMethod=='memcache'){
                    $m = new Memcache();
                    $m = memcache_connect($host, $port,$timeout);
                    if(!$m){
                        echo "Can't connect to Memcache server";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if($saveMethod=='memcached'){
                    $m = new Memcached();
                    $m->addServer($host, $port);
                }

                $session_data= $m->get($_COOKIE['adminhtml']);

                break;

            case 'redis'://Tested by Elias Soares
                $session_data = Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/session')->read($_COOKIE['a‌​dminhtml']);
                if(!is_string($session_data))
                    $session_data=serialize($session_data);
                break;
        }

        if(isset($session_data) && strpos($session_data,'Mage_Admin_Model_User'))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    return false;

    }
```

Original Source: [Magento: Prüfe Admin Session/Login im Frontend](https://peters-christoph.de/tutorials/magento-pruefe-admin-session-logi-im-frontend/)

Comment: I've submitted a edit on this code to support redis driver successfully:
`$session_data = Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/session')->read($_COOKIE['adminhtml']);`

Comment: @EliasSoares I have just added your suggestion with credits

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [Cross Area Sessions](https://github.com/astorm/Magento_CrossAreaSessions).  It does what you ask, and more, but is a relatively young project.  I think this is one to keep an eye on.